# Can I safely remove a usb device from a win 7 computer that is turned off?

Tags: windows-7, usb

Can I safely remove a usb device from a win 7 computer that is turned off? Or do I need to turn on the computer and "unmount" the drive 1st?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely remove the device from the computer. The "safely remove device" feature is simply making sure none of Window's resources are attached to the device before you remove it; therefore, if the computer is off, Windows does not have any processes attached to your device.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric said, it is safe to remove the device if the computer is turned off. However, note that "safely" here is in reference to "safely removing", NOT safety of data. If the computer suddenly lost power in the middle of a write, you can still "safely unplug" the USB device, but data on it could be corrupted.

Comment: That's mostly irrelevant because turning it back on wouldn't complete the write anyway.  From the standpoint of "it's finished all the writing it will do", it's technically "safe to remove"

Comment: Correct, but for most people, when they ask if something is safe, they're wondering whether their DATA is safe. It's misleading to tell someone, "Yes, it's safe, but your data may not be."